# Everything publishes on administrator account instead of the current user in Facebook Unity SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I've been working with Facebook Unity SDK for a few days and it's a real struggle to get things done with it.

So the problem I'm facing right now is that everything: Shares,Scores API,Photo Sharing is being done on the administrator account instead of that account which I'm currently using.

**Example:**

I've got a score of *1000* points in my game on **Account B** ( Which is a test user on my app), and then I'll try to upload/attach that score to it's Facebook account.
Instead, that score is being uploaded/attached to my **Account A** ( which is administrator account on that app ).
Same thing follows for pictures, shares etc.

Code for uploading/attaching score to FB account:

```
public void WriteScoreToFBAccount()
{
   Debug.Log("Trying to Upload attach Score to FB account...\n");
   lg.WriteToTextUIObject("Trying to Upload attach Score to FB account...\n");

   var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
   wwwForm.AddField("score", 1999);
   FB.API("/me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, FacebookProcessCallBack, wwwForm);  
}
```

Code for sharing the picture:

```
public void TakeAScreenShot()
{
    Debug.Log("Taking a Screenshot and trying to Upload it to FB...\n");
    lg.WriteToTextUIObject("Taking a Screenshot and trying to Upload it to FB...\n");

    ShareStatusMainWindowBackImage.SetActive(true);

    var width = Screen.width;
    var height = Screen.height;
    var tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();
    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, "InteractiveConsole.png");
    FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, FacebookProcessCallBack, wwwForm);
}
```

**Example 2: [UPDATED]**

```
Debug.Log("Trying to get FB friends Score...\n");
lg.WriteToTextUIObject("Trying to get FB friends Score...\n");

CurrentFacebookProcess = "GetFBScoreBoard";


string url = "https" + "://graph.facebook.com/" + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.UserId + "/?fields=scores%7Bapplication%2Cscore%7D&";
url += "access_token=" + AccessToken.CurrentAccessToken.TokenString;
WWWForm wwwForm = new WWWForm();
FB.API(url, HttpMethod.GET, FacebookProcessCallBack, wwwForm);
```

**As from the FB Unity SDK docs:**

*AccessToken
A class in the Facebook.Unity namespace containing the access token granted to your app when the user most recently authorized it*
Shouldn't it be the access token just for that user because he authorized it?
Or it's not the case and the user only authorized the app?

**Example 3: Login procedure [ Updated]**

```
public void LogIntoFB_Publish()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting a login proccess with publish permissions...\n");
    lg.WriteToTextUIObject("Starting a login proccess with publish permissions...\n");
    FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(new List<string>() { "publish_actions"}, AuthCallback);
}
public void LogIntoFB_Read()
{
    Debug.Log("Starting a login proccess with read permissions...\n");
    lg.WriteToTextUIObject("Starting a login proccess with read permissions...\n");
    FB.LogInWithReadPermissions(new List<string>() { "public_profile", "user_games_activity", "user_friends" }, AuthRead);
}
```

Developers console:

[image]

I'm new to Facebook SDK in general, so any tips are appreciated.

BTW, Facebook SDK is fully configured on this Unity project by their tutorial here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted

So my question is why everything that I publish through the FB app goes to my administrator account instead of the current account logged in in that game?

Also, I was wondering can it be related to the thing that my App is not approved yet, but still the test users should work?

Comment: I really looking forward to solving this!Any tips or suggestions are appreciated!!!

Comment: What `/me` refers to, depends on the access token you are using. In this case it must mean that you are using the token for your app admin account, and not the token of the user who is actually using your app. Have you hard-coded the token anywhere …?

Comment: Make sure that you are really logged in as the account you think you are. Make a debug output of your access token, and then debug it, to see which user account it belongs to.

Comment: I'll try that right now and will tell you the results.BTW, I updated the answer @CBroe , Look at example 2 [ Updated]

Comment: Shockingly enough, the access token for both users is the same. So I somehow need to generate unique access token for the user?@CBroe

Comment: Well yeah, of course ... you get a user access token by implementing the login flow.

Comment: Could you tell me more about it?@CBroe

Comment: Because I'm doing the login thing, look at Example 3 in the question above. @CBroe

Comment: Are you testing this on mobile, or desktop? Especially on mobile, switching users can be tricky. Suggest you remove the app from both user’s settings, under https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and then login again.

Comment: I'm testing it on mobile, I tried removing the app several days ago and it didn't work, but I'll try one more time.

Comment: Well , now it didn't post at all, but it gave all of the permissions to the account B, which is my desired result. The app returned no errors as if it would've posted the photo. Sounds very strange.

Comment: Tho it got the user id wrong, the user id corresponds to the administrator account, but the permissions were given to the real account. WTF  @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem by doing this:
 1. Implementing a login flow ( Huge thanks to user @CBroe ) by  **Logging out** if someone is already **Logged in** with a simple if statement:

```
if (FB.IsLoggedIn == true)
{
  Debug.Log("[Facebook SDK]: Already LOGGED In, LOGGIN OUT...\n");
  FB.LogOut();
}
else if (FB.IsLoggedIn == false)
  Debug.Log("[Facebook SDK]: User is NOT LOGGED IN, NOT DOING ANYTHING...\n");
```

Hope this helps someone.

**Tips:**

- Also as mentioned by @CBroe , it's indeed very hard to switch accounts on mobile, so be sure to not have multiple accounts ready for loggin in as it messes with Facebook SDK. **Have only one account logged in.**
- **Be aware that once someone is logged in on Facebook SDK, FB SDK doesn't care that you are trying to login with another account**, instead he makes all the requests, publishes stuff on the last ( or current ) account logged in.
- And if you are testing Facebook integration with your app, please make sure your app is **NOT LIVE** ( the little green icon near the app in Facebook Developers Console ) and it's in **DEVELOPMENT mode**, and you'are testing with the User assigned to tester role.